# Most Pythonic way of checking if an assignment changed the target object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to compare 2 dicts and make them equal (assigning a -> b). I also need to know if any value changed as if so, I need to run a computationally expensive function. I came up with some code that works, but it looks not pythonic at all.

Is there a more pythonic way??

```
   def sync_data(activity_update_response, existing_quote):
        data_changed = False
        if activity_update_response["source"]["firstName"] != existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"]["firstName"]:
            activity_update_response["source"]["firstName"] = existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"]["firstName"]
            data_changed = True

        if activity_update_response["source"]["lastName"] != existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"]["surname"]:
            activity_update_response["source"]["lastName"] = existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"]["surname"]
            data_changed = True

        # ( ... )
        # repeat for 4 more fields

        if data_changed:
            # this is slow
            recalculate_hashes(activity_update_response)
```

Comment: So you want to merge them both? `new_dict = {**a, **b}`

Comment: Is there a reason why the code *changing* the dict in the first place cannot trigger the expensive function as required?

Comment: If firstName and lastName (and the other fields) are the only keys you can reduce the checks to one: "if activity_update_response["source"] != existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"]" (but don't reduce assignment in the same way).

Comment: @Torxed , I want to avoid running recalculate hashes if there was no change in the first dictionary.

Comment: These are not the only keys, there are more. Also I want to recalculate the hashes at the very end so I just do it once.

Comment: At the very least, stop repeating `activity_update_response["source"]`; create a temporary variable `update = activity_update_response["source"]` and use that. The same goes for `existing_quote["origin"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the keys to update, then update the dict and recalculate the hashes. The new assignment expression operator in Python 3.8 comes in handy.

```
def sync_data(activity_update_response, existing_quote):
    # XXX Pick good names
    a = activity_update_response["source"]
    e = existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"]
    fields = ["lastName", "firstName", ...]

    #if (keys_to_update := [x for x in fields if a[x] != e[x]]):
    keys_to_update = [x for x in fields if a[x] != e[x]]
    if keys_to_update:
        recalculate_hashes(activity_update_response)
        for key in keys_to_update:
            a[key] = e[key]
```

Comment: I refactored some of the names as they were too descriptive to use put here.
This is used in a flask container with python 3.6.8, is this assignment operator not in that version?

Comment: No; as I said, it's new to Python 3.8 (which is still in beta). It's really just an optimization; I'll update with the code that works currently.

Answer (score 0):

I think storing the variable in `data_changed` is a pretty good way to go. I think the reason that this doesn't look Pythonic is that you're repeating yourself (not DRY).

I haven't tested this, but you could try pursuing something more along these lines.

```py
def sync_data(activity_update_response, existing_quote):
    data_changed = False

    origin = existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"]
    source = activity_update_response["source"]

    for field in ("firstName", "lastName",):  # Extend with 4 more fields
        data_changed = data_changed or origin[field] != source[field]
        source[field] = origin[field]

    if data_changed:
        # this is slow
        recalculate_hashes(activity_update_response)
```

Comment: `data_changed = data_changed or ...`; you don't want to reset it to `False` once it becomes `True`.

Comment: I think one of the fields comes from a different path in the dict so I might not be able to do it all in a for loop, but I'll try this for the others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make code, more readable, I would suggest:

```
def sync_data(activity_update_response, existing_quote):
    Fields = ("firstName", "lastName", )# add 4 more fields
    for field in Fields:
        if activity_update_response["source"][field] != existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"][field]
            activity_update_response["source"].update({f: existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"][f] for f in Fields})
            recalculate_hashes(activity_update_response)
            break
```

I do not see much more refactoring to do as this is essentially what you are trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the original code; this will recalculate the hashes on the first change, and ignore the rest of the fields. The goal is to make update *all* the fields, then recalculate the hashes if *any* field changed.

Comment: It does exactly the same thing as the original code Mr. Please, read the original question. BTW. I made #todo comment while in edit mode as I missed fields updating. And it looks like only checked fields are supposed to be updated.

Comment: No, it doesn't. With the `break`, `lastName` won't be updated if `firstName` is. The OP updates all differing fields, regardless of which ones have already been updated, *then* recalculates *once* if indicated.

Comment: won't this potentially calculate recalculate_hashes() more than once?

Comment: Here:
```activity_update_response["source"].update({f: existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"][f] for f in Fields})```
All fields are updated.

Comment: No it won't. Break will stop it from reoccurring (once break is 'executed' the loop is finished).

Comment: OK, I see what you are doing now. It's a bit wonky to have two different iterations over `Fields`. No more downvote, but no upvote either.

Comment: I missed that update is required at first, so actually I would reverse the operation order. Look next anwer -> much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom dictionary class that knows if it was changed:

```
class DictThatKnowsIfItChanged(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
       self.data_changed = True
       super().__setitem__(key, value)
    def reset_data_changed(self):
       self.data_changed = False
```

and use it for your variable activity_update_response. You could also want to overload the `update` method.

Deriving a standard class to fit your needs is rather pythonic.

Comment: It looks like he wants to track only few fields so additional 'if' statement would be required.

Comment: oh, so it'd need a `self.keys_i_want_to_track` list, and `self.data_changed = key in self.keys_i_want_to_track` instead of the True.

Answer (score 0):

```
# it is good idea to define it in outside scope as it does never change
Fields = ("firstName", "lastName", ) # add 4 more fields

def sync_data(activity_update_response, existing_quote):
    update_dict = {field: existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"][field] for field in Fields if activity_update_response["source"][field] != existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"][field]}
    # or use get if some of the keys might not be available, example:
    update_dict = {field: existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"][field] for field in Fields if activity_update_response["source"].get(field, None) != existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"].get(field, None)}
    if update_dict:
        activity_update_response["source"].update(update_dict )
        recalculate_hashes(activity_update_response)
```

Consider using get as described in code (it is very simple and it protects your code from unnecessary exceptions).

I would go even futher with this code and write it like this:

```
FieldsToCheck = ("firstName", "lastName", ) # add 4 more fields

def sync_data(dict_1, dict_2): # change name of arguments
    # or use get if some of the keys might not be available, example:
    change = {field: dict_2[field] for field in FieldsToCheck if dict_1[field] != dict_2[field]}
    if change :
        dict_1.update(change)
        recalculate_hashes(activity_update_response)

# to execute this function pass folowing parameters:
sync_data(activity_update_response["source"], existing_quote["origin"]["applicant"])
```

Why such approach? Work on simple data, it makes your code easy to understand.